# How can I use ng-click to dynamically reload ng-repeat data?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a page that contains an `ng-repeat` directive. The `ng-repeat` works when the page first loads, but I want to be able to use `ng-click` to refresh the contents of the `ng-repeat`. I have tried the following code but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
<div ng-click="loadItems('1')">Load 1st set of items</div>
<div ng-click="loadItems('2')">Load 2nd set of items</div>
...

<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">>
        // stuff
    </tr>
</table>
```

ItemsCtrl:

```
$scope.loadItems = function (setID) {
    $http({
        url: 'get-items/'+setID,
        method: "POST"
    })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.items = data;
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
    });
};
```

I was hoping that my call to `loadItems()` would cause the `ng-repeat` directive to reload with the new data obtained from my server.

Comment: is your code getting inside sucess function and do you get proper array from the server .Kindly check network data in chrome network tab

Answer (score 10):

Add a broadcast in your callback and subscribe to it in your controller.

*This should really be in a service btw*

```
itemsService.loadItems = function (setID) {
    $http({
        url: 'get-items/'+setID,
        method: "POST"
    })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.items = data;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('updateItems', data);
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
    });
};
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.$on("updateItems",function(d){
  $scope.items = d;
});
```

So whenever you `ng-click="update(id)"`

```
$scope.update = function(id){
    itemsService.loadItems(id);
}
```

Your `items` will automatically update because it is subscribed.

Comment: Where do I place the ``itemsService.loadItems =`` block of code? Does it go in a module?

Comment: @StephanieCaldwell It's a style of declaring an object in a service. Look into service functions.

Comment: Will any one please provide working jsfiddle or Demo for the same?